# ERB after <applet> tag doesn't render

Tags: java, html, ruby-on-rails, applet

I have a page that contains a Java applet. The applet is in the `_program.html.erb` partial. Here's the simplified ERB:

```
    <%= render "program" %>
    <div class="buttons" style="text-align:center; margin-top: 20px">
      BUTTONS <!--this doesn't render, but it renders if I remove the applet tag in _program, below. It's not that the buttons are blocked from view - they're not in the HTML source -->
    </div>
```

Here's `_program.html.erb`:

```
      <applet archive="<%= program.compiled.url %>" code="<%= program.name %>" />
```

The applet renders, but nothing after it renders, including the ERB and HTML after it and the footer partials. The HTML before the applet tag are closed properly after the applet tag. I found that using `<embed>` instead of `<applet>` fixes it (ie things after the program render again), but does anyone know why? Specifically:

1. Why does Rails not return any markup after the applet?
2. Why does using `<embed>` work?

Comment: It's not in the HTML source?  Or your browser isn't rendering it?  Two very different things.

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom as I mentioned in the HTML comment above, "they're not in the HTML source"

Comment: The 'HTML' as shown is utterly invalid.  Use a [validation service](http://validator.w3.org/) to check the output as it arrives in the browser.  The best way to deploy a JWS app. or applet is to use the [Deployment Toolkit Script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/depltoolkit_index.html).

Comment: @AndrewThompson if you mean because it doesn't have `<head>`, `<body`, etc, that's because I only wanted to show the relevant parts of the code. The entire HTML is hundreds of lines. If you mean because <applet /> is invalid, yes, that did turn out to be the problem. But you could have been clearer.

Comment: *"But you could have been clearer."*  A) That is what a validation service is for. B)  You could have been paying me enough to spoon feed these things to you. - BTW - did the validation service highlight the *other* two missing attributes in that HTML 3.2 based `applet` element?

Answer (score 0):

It was dead simple. `<applet />` should have been `<applet></applet>`. [Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/index/elements.html).